# Loop through HashSet and HashMap in JSP and print the result

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to do the below thing in JSP starting from `for loop`- I just want to loop HashSet and HashMap and print the result

```
private static HashMap<Long, Long> histogram = new HashMap<Long, Long>();
private static Set<Long> keys = histogram.keySet();

for (Long key : keys) {
    Long value = histogram.get(key);
    System.out.println("MEASUREMENT, HG data, " + key + ":" + value);
}
```

I am working with Spring MVC, so I added these two things in my `model`

```
model.addAttribute("hashSet", (keys));
model.addAttribute("histogram", (histogram));
```

And in my JSP page, I was doing something like this to emulate the above `JAVA code` but it was giving me an exception that something is wrong in my JSP page.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Performance Testing:</legend>
        <pre>

            <c:forEach items="${hashSet}" var="entry">
            Key = ${entry.key}, value = ${histogram}.get(${entry.key})<br>
            </c:forEach>


        </pre>
        <br />
</fieldset>
```

Exception I got-

```
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'key' not found on type java.lang.Long
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:195)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$400(BeanELResolver.java:172)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:281)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:62)
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: No one can help you out without knowing what the exception says exactly. "Something is wrong" is not enough information to go on.

Comment: edited the question. Sorry about that Richard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to make use of `keySet` to access the `values` in the `HashMap`. When you iterate over `HashMap` using `<c:forEach..`>, you get back the `EntrySet`, for which you can use: - `EntrySet#getKey()` and `EntrySet#getValue()` directly: -

```
<c:forEach items="${histogram}" var="entry">
     Key = ${entry.key}, value = ${entry.value}<br>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit for the help. Please take a closer look into my question. I need to extract data from HashMap I guess. Some part of your answer make sense to me

Comment: @TechGeeky.. Problem is, you can't call functions like that in JSTL. So, you can't call `map.get(key)` method. For that, you have to create a custom tag, which defines a custom function in some TagHandler class, which will return your map.get(key) value. Which of course is a more tedious task.

Comment: I see.. So I guess instead of using HashSet I can directly iterate HashMap right?

Comment: @TechGeeky.. Exactly. Take a look at the for loop I posted. It iterates over the hashmap, and returns the EntrySet. And you can then use its getKey() and getValue() method.