# Printing HashMap in a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, hashmap, jstl

I am using Spring Framework and I want to print a `HashMap` in a JSP using JSTL's `ForEach` loop.

Here is my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addContact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addContact(@ModelAttribute("contact")
                            Contact contact, BindingResult result)
    {
        ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
        String msg = "Jon Doe added to database";

        modelMap.put("message", msg);

        Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        myMap.put("A", "DD");
        myMap.put("B", "EE");
        myMap.put("C", "FF");

        System.out.println("***********************************");
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
        }
        modelMap.put("myMap", myMap);

        return new ModelAndView("hello", modelMap);

    }
```

And following is my JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hi there</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Hello</h2>
    <c:out value="${message}"></c:out> <br> <br> <br>
    <a href="http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/">back</a>

    <br>

    <c:forEach items="${myMap}" var="entry">
    Key : <c:out value="${entry.key}"/>  Value: <c:out value="${entry.value}"/> <br />
    </c:forEach> 

</body>
</html>
```

I have used the logic explained by [in this accepted answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14613585/3382733)

> But still I am unable to print the HashMap. Getting error *HTTP Status 500*

Here is my console output:

```
13:23:11,756 INFO  [EARDeployer] Started J2EE application: file:/C:/jboss-4.0.2_1/server/default/deploy/SpringMVCEAR.ear
13:23:54,863 INFO  [STDOUT] ***********************************
13:23:54,863 INFO  [STDOUT] Key = A, Value = DD
13:23:54,863 INFO  [STDOUT] Key = B, Value = EE
13:23:54,863 INFO  [STDOUT] Key = C, Value = FF
13:23:55,098 ERROR [[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ValueExpression
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
```

> When I remove the forEach tag in my JSP my page is getting displayed properly with message *Jon Doe added to database*

Thanks for the help in advance :)

**EDIT** I have also tried without the forEach loop body:

```
<c:forEach items="${myMap}" var="entry">
        Something
    </c:forEach>
```

*Still Same error*

Comment: Have you tried without c:out ? <c:forEach items="${myMap}" var="entry">
    Key : ${entry.key} Value: ${entry.value} <br />
    </c:forEach>

Comment: @Henrik, yup but still i am getting same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is jar conflict

Remove this :

```
jstl-1.2.jar
```

From the `WEB-INF/lib` directory

Comment: Hmm I think you have a wrong version of a jar, in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory, do you have some `jstl*.jar` ?

Comment: I don't this so, cause my c:out is working find when I won't add any forEach, anyhow I am having jstl-1.2.jar, and standard-1.1.2.jar in my lib folder

Comment: could you remove (or put in another dir temporarely) the jstl-1.2.jar ? or back to 1.1.2 version.

Comment: I think the problem is jar conflict. Could you please mark as valid the answer please to close the issue.

Comment: Got it my web.xml is declared as Servlet 2.4, and for using `jstl-1.2` we need at least Servlet 2.5. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Can you please edit you answer with the actual cause so that I can accept it.